# user_id conflict for multiple guards laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, session

I'm new to Laravel and i created two guards "user guard"(default one) and "admin guard". And i'm saving auth sessions in database instead of file.

Now the problem is user id is causing conflict in sessions table. 
For example, if i create a new user in users table and new admin account in admin table both would have same id in sessions table and since the id is not unique it's automatically logging me in to admin account even though if i just login as normal user.

I've already searched on Google but couldn't find anything useful. Only this guy has asked same question but not working answer:
[Multi session tables in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418791/multi-session-tables-in-laravel)

Here's my code:
config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',

    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,

    ]
],
```

AdminLoginController.php

```
if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
    $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
    return redirect()->route('admin');

}
```

Comment: It would be easier to maintain 1 user table, and manage their permissions either as a field, or in another table

Comment: Thanks but different table for both roles is the goal for this question :)

Comment: Are you sure It's conflicting? I believe you just don't use the guards correctly. How to know the user_id causing the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

There probably shouldn't be a separate table and separate eloquent model for an admin, as an admin *is* a User. They are just a User with elevated permissions.

Instead of creating a separate model, guard, and provider for admins, consider attaching roles and/or permissions to your User model to track if a User is an administrator.

Here's a good package to help with that: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: Thanks but I wonder if it's possible at all or not in laravel. I've something similar in pure php but not sure about laravel so I'm here to get help from laravel guys.

Comment: This is a good answer and advice, but it's not answering his question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's conflicting. I believe you just don't use the guards correctly.

You need to make sure, you **never** call `Auth::user()` if you're logging in as `Admin`. You **should always** need to use `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`.

Comment: I'm using it correctly `Auth::user()` for user and `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` for admin.

Comment: @Markian Can you post your full Login controller (ex. `LoginController`) code and your home controller (ex. `HomeController`) code?

Answer (score 0):

extend the laravel default `DatabaseSessionHandler`  and override the `addUserInformation` function

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
use Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler;

class CustomDatabaseSessionHandler extends DatabaseSessionHandler
{
    /**
     * Add the user information to the session payload.
     *
     * @param array $payload
     * @return $this
     * @throws BindingResolutionException
     */
    protected function addUserInformation(&$payload): static
    {
        if ($this->container->bound(Guard::class)) {
            info(($this->user() ? get_class($this->user()) : null));
            $payload['userable_type'] = $this->user() ? get_class($this->user()) : null;
            $payload['userable_id'] = $this->userId();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the currently authenticated user's ID.
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BindingResolutionException
     */
    protected function user(): mixed
    {
        return $this->container->make(Guard::class)->user();
    }
}
```

then register the driver in `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot(): void
    {
        Session::extend('custom-database', function ($app) {
            $table = $app['config']['session.table'];
            $lifetime = $app['config']['session.lifetime'];
            $connection = $app['db']->connection($app['config']['session.connection']);

            return new CustomDatabaseSessionHandler($connection, $table, $lifetime, $app);
        });
    }
```

change your sessions table migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->string('userable_type')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('userable_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
            $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
        });
    }
```

then change session driver in your `.env`  file

```
SESSION_DRIVER=custom-database
```

now the sessions stored in the database are polymorphic